# ESP8266 TCP packet fragmentation

Tags: c, tcp, esp8266, arduino-esp8266, esp8266wifi

I am trying to send TCP packets to a remote server, using the Wemos D1 Mini Pro (ESP8266), configured in **lwIP v2 high bandwidth** mode (`TCP_MSS = 1460`, `LWIP_ FEATURES = 1`).

I set a maximum buffer size of 1810 bytes :

```
#define MAX_BUFFER_SIZE 1810
```

I declare the buffer as a global static variable :

```
static uint8_t buffer[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];
```

and I am continually sending `packetSize` (user-definable size) packets using TCP_write :

```
uint16_t sent = TCP.write((uint8_t*)buffer,packetSize);
```

most of the times I get `sent` equal to packetSize, however, once a while the function returns a smaller value. For instance, if packetSize = 1135, I usually get the first bad value equal to 650 and a few zero values after that. Normal operation restores after a few failed sends.

I am looking for the reasons behind this fragmentation issue.

Thoughts : should I use a buffer size (currently 1860) smaller than TCP_MSS = 1460, no matter if `packetSize` is actually smaller than `TCP_MSS` ? If yes, should I try to declare `buffer` as a dynamic array with size equal to `packetSize` ?

Comment: I am betting that you are calling TCP.write() until the underlying tx buffer is full. This buffer is likely a multiple of TCP_MSS. if the underlying buffer is TCP_MSS * 2 in size, then calling TCP.write(1135) just 3 times will result in only stuffing 650 bytes into the tx buffer.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what it happens. The TCP_SND_BUF is 2 * 1460 = 2920 and it gets stuffed with three 1135 packets, so the last one reads as 650. I couldn't find a way to increase this buffer, even when editing lwipopts.h. My module is Wemos D1 mini pro.